# SML binary tree reduce function

Tags: tree, binary-tree, sml, reduce

So I've got an assignment in SML and I need a bit of help getting started.

The problem goes like this

> Write a function btree_size of type 'a btree -> int that returns the
>   size of the binary tree. (The size of a binary tree is the number of
>   elements in the binary tree). For example, btree_size (Node (Leaf, 1,
>   Node (Leaf, 2, Leaf))) should return 2. Your function must use the
>   provided btree_reduce function and should be at most 3 lines long.

The btree_reduce function is this

```
(* A reduction function. *)
     (* btree_reduce : ('b * 'a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a tree -> 'b) *)
    fun btree_reduce f b bt =
      case bt of
      Leaf => b
      | Node (l, x, r) => f (btree_reduce f b l, x, btree_reduce f b r)
```

How in the world do I make a btree_size function that takes a btree and uses the reduce function to give me the size of the tree?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a homework, I will refrain from giving direct answers. :)

I'd proceed as follows:

- get acquainted with computing the size of the tree (by writing a recursive function which meets your specification)
- see what is common between the function you wrote and btree_reduce (or, what could be abstracted out from the function you wrote)

This is one of the many ways, of course.

Comment: Yes recursively the function is a breeze.
fun btree_size bt = 
     case bt of 
         Leaf=>0
         |Node(btl, x, brt)=> btree_size btl + 1 + btree_size btr


I don't know how to tell the reduce function to add 1 each time. I know we're going to do something like this 
       reduce("tell it to add", 0, bt)
I just dont know how to tell it to add one each time

Comment: I think you've already figured it out. The function f that you pass to btree_reduce takes 3 arguments. The first argument and the third arguments are the results of two recursive invocations, right? In the inductive case of btree_size, the result has the form x + 1 + y, where x = btree_size btl and y = btree_size btr. Do you need more hints?

Comment: yes I do understand that. I do not know how to create a function to pass to reduce that tells it to do that though. Everything I've tried hasn't compiled. Do I need to create an external helper function or is there some SML functionality built in that will do this?

Comment: just tried this. 
 fun myAdder a b c =
 1 + a + c;

fun btree_size bt =
 btree_reduce(myAdder, 0, bt);
and it blew up

Comment: So you're tripped by the syntax, correct? Have you tried fn (x, a, y) => ...? BTW, there is a helpful keyword "local" which can be used as an "inside-out let".

Comment: fun btree_size bt =
 btree_reduce(fn(x,a,y)=> 1 + x + y, 0, bt); This blew up as well. what is an "inside out let"